# Omitting fields when using Jackson CsvMapper to serialize POJOs

Tags: java, serialization, csv, jackson

I'm serialising a POJO to CSV using jackson.  My problem is that I can't work out how to ommit certain fields when serializing.  I don't want to have to annotate the POJO as it would affect the JSON and XML serialisation which requires those fields.  For example

```
public class POJO {
  public string field1; //required by JSON and CSV
  public string field2; //only required by JSON
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: anyone?  This has been really bugging me.  I've has to convert the bean to a different class just to get it to ommit the fields.

Answer (score 6):

What worked for me was setting the `CsvMapper` setting `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator.Feature.IGNORE_UNKNOWN` to true

```
CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper(); //com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvMapper
MAPPER.configure(Feature.IGNORE_UNKNOWN, true);
```

adding the desired columns to the schema.

```
CsvSchema schema = CsvSchema.builder();
    .addColumn("A")
    .addColumn("C")
    .build();
```

for my POJO

```
public class MyClass{

    @JsonProperty("A")
    private string a;

    @JsonProperty("B")
    private string b;

    @JsonProperty("C")
    private string c;

    //getters setters

}
```

To get the CSV string I did this:

```
List<MyClass> list = new MyClass();
MyClass row = new MyClass();

row.setA("Value A");
row.setB("Value B");
row.setC("Value C");

list.add(row);

ObjectWriter ow = mapper.writer(schema);
String csv = ow.writeValueAsString(list);
```

Output (withHeaders):

```
A,C
"Value A","Value C"
```